# SCNPhysicsContactDelegate must at least implement one selector

Tags: ios, scenekit

[SCNKit ERROR] SCNPhysicsContactDelegate must at least implement one selector

I am receiving the above error after setting my viewController as the contactDelegate for my project. I cannot find what I have forgotten to implement, below is my code for loading the scene.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *) self.view;

    //set the background colour
    scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //setup the scene
    SCNScene *scene = [self setupScene];

    //present it
    scnView.scene = scene;

    //initial point of view
    scnView.pointOfView = _cameraNode;

    //plug game logic
    scnView.delegate = self;

    //physicsworld
    scnView.scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
    scnView.scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)didBeginContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact {
    NSLog(@"contact");
}
```

.h

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate>

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not implementing any methods from the protocol, so it's an error to declare conformance.

You probably want to implement [`physicsWorld:didBeginContact:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsContactDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNPhysicsContactDelegate/physicsWorld:didBeginContact:), not just `didBeginContact:`.